# Finding the number in a list that differs in parity

Tags: algorithm, ruby, comparative-review

> Given any string with a series of numbers find out which one of the numbers differs from the others in evenness and return its position.

**Examples:**

- `"2 4 6 7 8 10"` returns 4
- `"3 5 7 9 10"` returns 5

I found 2 different ways to do so, but I'm wondering what is the best approach in matter of time complexity.

**Solution 1**

```
def num_test(numbers)
  (i = numbers.split.map(&:to_i)).index(i.partition(&:odd?).find(&:one?).first)+1
end
```

**Solution 2**

```
def num_test(numbers)
  numbers.index(numbers.split.map(&:to_i).partition(&:odd?).find(&:one?).first.to_s)+1
end
```

Also, any other solution is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one way we can do it is by counting the first three elements. If more than one is odd, it means the sequence is odd, and we should look for an even number. If one or less is odd, the sequence is even, and we should look for an odd number.

```
a1 = "2 4 6 7 8 10"
a2 = "3 5 7 9 10"

def index_of_outlier(string)
  array = string.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
  count_of_odd = (array[0..2]).count { |i| i.odd? }
  if count_of_odd > 1
    array.index { |i| i.even? }
  else
    array.index { |i| i.odd? }
  end
end

puts index_of_outlier(a1) #=> 3 
puts index_of_outlier(a2) #=> 4
```

This looks messy, but it gets the job done quickly. The lower bound is \$3 + 1\$ iterations, and the upper bound is \$3 + n - 1\$. This makes it \$O(n)\$.

You need three iterations to determine the nature of the sequence and up to \$n - 1\$ more to find the solution.

I'm not sure how `partition` works under the hood, but I assume it traverses the array at least once. This means my solution will perform better if the target index is lower than \$n - 5\$.

If you want the char position in the string and not the array index, just add one to the result (as you are doing in your own solutions).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk). In combination with [`lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy) it should be efficient.

```
def num_test(numbers)                                         
  ints = numbers.split.map(&:to_i)                            
  odd, chunk = ints.lazy.chunk(&:odd?).first                  
  chunk.size == 1 && odd != ints[2].odd? ? 1 : chunk.size + 1 
end
```

Comment: It fails on `"4 5 7 9"`

Comment: Ok, I forgot the case when the first value is the wrong one. Thanks for the hint. I'll adapt the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are three stop conditions depending on the oddity of gaps between the 3rd, 2nd, and 1st most recent number:

- 0 1 -> 1st (the last one) is the answer
- 1 0 -> 3rd
- 1 1 -> 2nd

You can run through string lazily using `.scan` -- with `break` it has to be faster than `.split`.

```
def num_test numbers
  n1 = d2 = d1 = nil
  numbers.scan(/\d+/).each_with_index do |s, i|
    if n1 # the first iteration doesn't let us calculate the gap
      d2, d1 = d1, (s.to_i - n1) % 2
      break i + 1 if d2 == 0 && d1 == 1
      break i - 1 if d2 == 1 && d1 == 0
      break i     if d2 == 1 && d1 == 1
    end
    n1 = s.to_i
  end
end
```